# Find a row into the database either the entry text contains or not hyphens, white spaces and apostrophes

Tags: sql, database

I have a table in a MySQL database with the column 'lastName'.

Some of the data of the 'lastName' column includes hyphens, white spaces and apostrophes, like:

- Atkinson-Lloyd
- O'Leary
- de la Fuente

I need to be able to search this data either my search text contains or not the hyphens, white spaces and apostrophes. So, for example, in the case of 'Atkinson-Lloyd', if I write in my form Atkinson Lloyd or AtkinsonLloyd, I want to match the Atkinson-Lloyd row. Same with O Leary or OLeary. And same with delaFuente or de-la-fuente.

How could I do that if I cannot modify my query?

Thank you :)

Comment: Regex can perhaps be used, or a custom tailed collation. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I am using a MySql database.

Comment: @jarlh, how it could be a collation for this?

Comment: not with MySQL, I'm afraid.

Comment: Why can you not modify the query? Is it a 3rd party dll , or some interface, or bizarre requirement?  How are you passing your search params?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which language your using, but the rough approach i usually use is as follows:
Take the users search input , and split on spaces.
Each string you get out of that you have to append to your query
and search_column like '%whatever was exploded%' (after exploding on spaces this will be just a single team.)

It lengthens the crap on your query , but im pretty sure that will handle what you need.
which in turn to your question you would end up with a query like
lastName like '%Atkinson%' and lastName like '%Lloyd%'

Comment: Thank you, Gauthier. The problem is I cannot modify the query.